# Incorrect icon association Mac - El Capitan

Tags: macos, mac, icons, finder, osx-el-capitan

I have recently switched from PC to Mac and since I am not very familiar with the environment I would like to ask for a help. My MacBook Air with El Capitan installed has problem with icons association. This problem applies for html, txt, microsoft office and pdf files. All of these files are displayed as universal white files (see image_01). What is curious though is that during first 2-3 seconds after boot up icons are shown correctly, or sort of, except for txt files (see image_02), sorry for the quality.

All solutions I found are outdated and none of them worked. Any tips for a beginner?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trying to show you a thumbnail view of the contents of those files (because it understands PDF, DOCX, and HTML file types).  It's a little ridiculous in my opinion, because that's only useful for pictures.  You'll notice too that when you hover over the icon you have left and right page navigation options as well (assuming there's more than one page).  Pretty stupid for an icon.

Anyway, here's how to turn that off:

From the menu bar at the top of the screen, click on View -> Show View Options. Then deselect Show Icon Preview.  That's it.  You may have to log off/back on but the icons will revert to their generic type icons.

Unfortunately, this applies to your pictures too.  You can't have it on for pictures but off for everything else.

Also note, this is a per-folder setting, so changing it will only affect the desktop.  You can click the Use as Default button if you want and it will apply to all folders.  You can then just turn the preview back on only for those folders that contain pictures.